# ASPX Mapping in web.config

Tags: asp.net

I've searched around for an answer to this question for a while. I'm working on a VB.NET project and I have several .aspx files I would like to map to different url paths. Is there a tagline for the mapping in the web.config file similar to mapping .jsp with web.xml in java:

```xml
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myjsp</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/hello.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
 
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>sample</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Hello</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Edit: I believe I can achieve what I am trying to do through UrlRewriter, but I cannot get this configuration to work because I do not know what references I have to make (Intelligencia.UrlRewriter doesn't exist as a reference assembly?)

```xml
  <configSections>
    <section name="rewriter" requirePermission="false" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/>
  </configSections>
  
  <system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>

  <rewriter>
    <rewrite url="WebForm1.aspx" to="WebForm1/" />
    <rewrite url="~/products/CDs.aspx" to="~/products.aspx?category=CDs" />
    <rewrite url="~/products/DVDs.aspx" to="~/products.aspx?category=DVDs"/>
  </rewriter>
```

It is also my understanding that if you are using IIS7, you have to replace the httpModule section with

```xml
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

to Map ~/WebForm1.aspx to ~/Web

```xml
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="rewriter" requirePermission="false" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/>
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/>
    </httpModules>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
    <urlMappings enabled="true">
      <add url="~/Web" mappedUrl="~/WebForm1.aspx" />
    </urlMappings>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule"/>
    </modules>
    <!-- THE FOLLOWING LINE MUST BE PRESENT FOR AJAX & VALIDATION TO WORK WITH URLREWRITER.NET -->
    <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <!--</handlers>-->
  </system.webServer>
  <!-- URL REWRITER -->
  <rewriter>
    <!--<rewrite url="~/WebForm1.aspx" to="~/WebForm2.aspx"/>-->
  </rewriter>
</configuration>
```

Inside of Configuration tags where the noted rewrite node will redirect, the name is modified by the URL mapping

This requires a reference made to Intelligencia.UrlRewriter to forward urls (but not rename), which I found on github.